# Data complexity measure

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, dataset, classification

As we strive to explain accuracy of machine learning algorithms, many authors suggest to start by degree of complexity in data.

I am working in data complexity measure like: class separability,overlapping and outlier measure, which affect classifier performance.

For example if classes are more separable, accuracy of classifier is also increased and classifier takes less time.

I want to calculate outlier measure of each data point in dataset and combine these measure and make one measure for outlier in dataset. How can i calculate outlier using k nearest neighbour or using k means clustering technique. 
Thanx in advance..

Comment: In what language & framework? I suppose this question belongs to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: We have a dataset of different categories like:medical ,software engineering ,machinery dataset etc...Language is not a bar

Comment: Yeah but how are you planning to parse the dataset and process them? Are you going to use Matlab or similar scientific oriented programs which provide much of the calculation logic?

Comment: If language is not a bar, you're asking for the [algorithm](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Yeah i am asking the algorithm for finding outlier..If preferred then c++

Comment: Then ask in [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), or just grab [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) and use its various packages for outlier

Comment: Basically you can learn some distribution for each class, or maybe even not one, and try to predict likelihood of point of some class with distributions of same class.
[Look here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.21.4309)

You can use gaussian distribution or any else. But i never implemented all this, so i'm not certain.